# Problem with third party Antivirus , android code not running

Tags: android, windows-7, antivirus, windows-firewall

My Android code makes a web service call when I run the code on my local Android Emulator using the URL: http://192.168.56.1/test/Service1.asmx .When I run the code in my emulator I get the desired output with the above URL but when I install app on my smartphone and tried using the same then there was an error saying connection refused. I have opened port 80 on my Windows 7 machine through the Firewall Settings.

Now I need to know how to unblock the firewall of my Mcafee AntiVirus such that the error of connection refusal is not present.

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

192.168.x.x network is a [private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) and cannot be accessed outside, i.e from actual android device in your case.

Android simulator works on your computer that is a part of the private network, so the 192.168.56.1 server is accessible. But actual android device works outside of your private network.

Place your webservice on a server with a [real ip-address](http://forums.techguy.org/web-email/443970-what-real-ip.html), or setup a firewall on the server with real ip-address to implement a passthrough connection via this real ip-address and port to your internal private network resource.

Comment: u mean there isn't any way to access the web service from my actual phone keeping the service on my laptop ? Do I have a buy a real server then ? How do I test my app then ?

Comment: I can't really figure out what to do ? is there any other solution for this ?

Comment: You do not need to **buy** a server. Check [this link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100309093010AAzsWPI)

Comment: Thanks for the link !! . Presently , I m using the services of my local ISP, do u think I should inform them if I need to get the real IP, will it affect the connection they are providing me. Sorry I have never tried this before, so I have a lot of questions...Also is it safe?

Comment: Can u tell me how should I go about it from here on ?

Comment: You may request your local ISP to purchase one real IP-address. Usually it does not cost much money. After that set-up the firewall on your computer and assign this real-ip address to your computer and it will be visible from outside. The important point is, that you need to setup the firewall to prevent outside attack on your laptop, because it will become visible from outside network after assigning a real-ip address.

Comment: And additional point. For testing purposes it is enough to purchase one real ip and assign it to your laptop. But if you want to use your application in a real production environment it is recommended to purchase a hosting plan (real ip included) and setup your web-service on the external server.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2460/discussion-between-parth-90-and-rafael-osipov)